# How can to fix Interface "App\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Aunthenticatable' not found" in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

This my code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Model implements Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Aunthenticatable
{
    use Authenticatable;

}
```

How can I resolve this error?

> "App\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Aunthenticatable not found"

Comment: There seems to be an extra `n` in your contracts name ( `AuNthenticatable` instead of `Authenticatable`, voting to close this as it seems to be a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't properly import `namespace`. Please try following code:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthContract;

class Admin extends Model implements AuthContract 
{ 
    use Authenticatable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write this. Hopefully this will solve your problem

```
<?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class AdminModelOL extends Authenticatable {

        use Notifiable;
       }
```

You should properly import your namespace